# What is the best way to return failure info in sub in Perl?

Tags: perl

Lets assume I have a sub `do_foo` which do some operations. It may either terminate successfully and returns true, or doesn't do the required operations for multiple reasons based on class states and return false.

```
sub do_foo {
    my $self = shift;

    my $status = 1; # Assume by default success operation
    my $error; # How to handle failed operation reason in this variable ?

    # Do some process here, based on it change operation status to 0
    # The error will also be set to identify why operation failed in case of failure
    # ....

    return $status;
}
```

I was thinking what is the best design to return the cause of operation failure ?

Here are my attempts:

**A. Return a list, in array context, with extra information about error**

- In case of success operation: return a list `(1)` if `wantarray` is
  true, scalar `1` otherwise
- In case of operation failed: return a list
  `(0, $error)` if `wantarray` is true, scalar `0` otherwise

**B. Also I think about throwing an exception in case of failed operation**, but I don't want to return exception in case of expected cases/scenarios/flows that can be handled without exceptions. **What I understand is that Exceptions are only for exceptional circumstances - ie, when they are not part of the normal flow of the code.**

So to summarize, my questions are:

1. What is the best code design for such scenario (multiple failure
   reasons or success) ?
2. Should the error message be a string ? or should I `use constant` in the class ? or what ? (BTW, I know that PBP 4.5 is against `use constant` )

Comment: What I understand as specified in my question that  Exceptions are only for exceptional circumstances - ie, when they are not part of the normal flow of the code. The failures are part of the flow not exceptional cases.

Comment: Ashraf, see Schwern's comments in reply to wprl's comment on the accepted answer to that question. It really doesn't pay to be dogmatic about "exceptions are only for exceptional situations!!!". That said, you haven't told us what kind of non-exceptional failures you foresee, so we can't really say how appropriate exceptions would (or wouldn't) be in this situation.

Comment: @Dave, I will give you some situations in my app. where the failure is part of the flow and not to be considered an exception ... do_foo is  buy_car (yup, it is a small agency for used cars selling), sometimes the car is already sold, sometimes it is checked now by another customer so it is in hold state, sometimes the agency detected a failure in the car and need to be repaired first, and many other situations which happen frequently and depend on the dynamic state of this class at moment t. I hope I was clear enough about being a failure in purchasing (part of the flow) not an exception.

Comment: die can work in a void context.  Then they have to trap if with an eval